# Preserving the distinctions between bools and floats when adding NaN to a pandas Series?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am adding data to a pandas `Series` via the `Series#append` method. Unfortunately, when `nan` is added to a `bool` Series, it is automatically converted to a `float` Series. Is there any way to avoid this conversion, or at least coerce it to `object` dtype, so as to preserve the distinction between `bool`s and `float`s?

```
>>> Series([True])                            
0    True
dtype: bool
>>> Series([True]).append(Series([np.nan]))
0     1
0   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: you could do ``Series([True],dtype=object)`` when you create it, though generally mixing these types of things is not recommented, maybe use a DataFrame

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. How exactly could I use a DataFrame to avoid this issue?  FWIW, this is a simplified minimal example, I actually am using multiple arrays wrapped as a DataFrame; the nans represent missing values, which I have to represent somehow.

Comment: see the docs here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html; a frame will allow you to have different dtypes in different columns; nan represents missing values

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you need to preserve the distinction?

Comment: @PhillipCloud: it's important because we expose the data to users. For example, through an interface that lets them modify data based on type. So it's confusing when they get boolean results as 1.0s and 0.0s instead of True/False, and error-prone when they can change them to any float, while the only sensible values are True/False.

Comment: @DunPeal its clear then a DataFrame is much more suited to what you need then (or separate Series)

Comment: @Jeff: what do you mean by "separate Series"?  Do you mean that for every Series `foo`, I should add a bool Series `foo_missing_values`, which is True for every missing value in `foo`?

Comment: Well if you have Series that are indexed the same, then its clear you should use a DataFrame, see @cpclouds answer; however if they are NOT indexed the same, then you could present the user with different Series (one float and one boolean); IMHO, this is much better off done with a DataFrame, must simpler; you can effectively have more indices if you need (either multi-level or use additional columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jeff said, the best way is going to be to append a `Series` with `object` `dtype`

Here's an example using `Series`

```
s = Series([True])
s.append(Series([nan], index=[1], dtype=object))
```

yielding

```
0    True
1     NaN
dtype: object
```

And one with a `DataFrame`:

```
df = DataFrame({'a': rand(10) > 0.5, 'b': randn(10)}, columns=list('ab'))
df2 = DataFrame({'a': Series([nan], dtype=object), 'b': [1.0]}, columns=df.columns, index=[len(df)])
df3 = df.append(df2)
print df3
print
print df3.dtypes
```

which gives

```
        a      b
0   False -0.865
1    True -0.186
2    True  0.078
3    True  0.995
4   False -1.420
5    True -0.340
6    True  0.042
7    True -0.627
8    True -0.217
9    True  1.226
10    NaN  1.000

a     object
b    float64
dtype: object
```

It's a bit clunky looking, but if you've already got the `Series` then you can do `s.astype(object)` to convert them to `object` `dtype` before appending.